# What technical flaw in the Secure Hash Standard was the NIST referring to?

Tags: sha-1, nist, shs

On July 11, 1994, [the NIST proposed an interesting revision](https://csrc.nist.gov/News/1994/Proposed-Revision-of-FIPS-180) to FIPS 180, about the Secure Hash Standard:

> A revision of Federal Information Processing Standard (FIPS) 180,
> Secure Hash Standard (SHS), is being proposed. This proposed revision
> **corrects *a technical flaw* that made the standard less secure** than had
> been thought. The algorithm is still reliable as a security mechanism,
> but [sic] the correction returns the SHS to the original level of security.

**What was the technical flaw?**

[FIPS PUB 180-1](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.FIPS.180-1), which specifies SHA-1, was published on 17 April, 1995. It superseded [FIPS PUB 180](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.FIPS.180), which was published on 11 May, 1993.

On the first page of FIPS PUB 180-1 it explains:

> **A circular left shift operation has been added** to  the specifications
> in section 7, line b, page 9 of FIPS 180 and its equivalent in section
> 8, line c, page 10 of FIPS180. **This revision improves the security
> provided  by this standard.** The SHA-1 is based on principles similar
> to those used by Professor Ronald L. Rivest of MIT when designing the
> **MD4** message digest algorithm 1, and is closely modelled [sic] after that
> algorithm.

Security was improved by the revision, but there is no explanation as to what the circular left shift remedied.

**Does anyone know what the original flaw was?**

Comment: Tthe intro in Xiaoyun Wang, Hongbo Yu ,Yiqun Lisa Yin's [_Efficient Collision Search Attacks on SHA-0_](https://doi.org/10.1007/11535218_1), in proceedings of Crypto 2005, is all I know about the issue. Later attacks have improved on their results.